# Transform gin.Context to context.Context

Tags: go, go-gin

Is there a way to transform
[`gin.Context`](https://godoc.org/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Context)
to [`context.Context`](https://golang.org/pkg/context/#Context)
in Go?
What should be used in building a Go microservice?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The standard library's [`context.Context`](https://golang.org/pkg/context/#Context) type is an interface, with the following methods:

- `Deadline() (deadline time.Time, ok bool)`
- `Done() <-chan struct{}`
- `Err() error`
- `Value(key interface{}) interface{}`

So any type that has these methods *is* a `context.Context`.

Looking at the [gin documentation](https://godoc.org/github.com/gin-gonic/gin), we see that the `gin.Context` type has all of these methods:

- [`Deadline`](https://godoc.org/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Context.Deadline)
- [`Done`](https://godoc.org/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Context.Done)
- [`Err`](https://godoc.org/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Context.Err)
- [`Value`](https://godoc.org/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Context.Value)

So it's already a `context.Context`. No conversion or transformation necessary.

Comment: How do you convert `*gin.Context` to `*context.Context`?

Comment: @wizulus: You don't. `*context.Context` doesn't make sense. `*gin.Context` already is a `context.Context`, so don't do any conversion.

Comment: If we weren't talking about pointers, I would agree. But my compiler seems to complain about this. A `pointer to gin.Context` is not a `pointer to context.Context`, even though `gin.Context` implements the `context.Context` interface. In my code, I had to de-reference the first pointer into a new variable, then use a pointer to that variable. I wonder if there's a way to do that without an intermediate variable, and preserve the memory location.

Comment: Yes, don't use a pointer to `context.Context`. pointers to interfaces practically never make any sense. If you're using `*context.Context` in your code, that is the bug.

Comment: But the context methods in gin.Context are no-ops. I think in most practical cases you actually want `ginCtx.Request.Context()`